# Run self executable shell script for files in the same folder

Tags: shell, sh

I would like to run a shell script from a folder it resides by double-clicking. Currently, it only works from the terminal if I cd to the folder and run bash screensVid.sh
At the moment it spits out this error ***.mp4: No such file or directory**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp4;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  ffmpeg -ss 5 -i "$i" -qscale:v 30 -frames:v 1 "${name}.jpg"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=`dirname $0`
echo $DIRECTORY
for i in $DIRECTORY/*.mp4;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  ffmpeg -ss 5 -i "$i" -qscale:v 30 -frames:v 1 "${name}.jpg"
done
```